# Extracting a substring from string in Python and putting it to a file

Tags: python, macos

I have a file in the following format

```
name@company.com, information
name@company2.com, information
....
```

What I need to do is read in the file and output the email address only to a file. I have the following code created

```
with open ('n-emails.txt') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  print (lines)
```

Can someone please show me how to only get the email part of the file and how to output it to a file this is all done on a mac.

Comment: `awk -F, '{ print $1 }' n-emails.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: I dont have awk on the mac and I need to use python

Comment: Use `company = split.line(',')` to get the company information in `company[0]` `for each line in f.readlines():`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this is a standard text file, not a .csv file with columns. I do not think it is a duplicate. It should be reopened. A plain split would work better.

Comment: it's a duplicate of some other question then. And no effort, no code provided: too broad anyway.

Comment: @sabbahillel if you think it should be reopened, flag the question explaining that. A mod will judge that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have flagged it to be reopened because there is sufficient code and sufficient information so that i can answer it as asked.

Comment: its NOT a duplicate and your awk code did not work too..

Comment: @sabbahillel: reopened, there's some (bad) code but an attempt has been made. BTW you're not the one who serially downvoted me by chance? dupehammering questions is not without risks... You'll have to be fast because I'll answer that :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No I did not downvote. I could not get to the answer, but it is good that you did. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @sabbahillel my apologies for asking you that! thanks for the +1. I just hope that it will help the OP and some other people. The idea of duplicate is not punishing people, but redirecting them to better answers, and avoiding pollution / making people answer non-duplicates instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 different ways of doing it:

without `csv` module: read each line, split according to tokens, strip the blanks, print:

```
with open ('n-emails.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    toks = line.split(",")
    if toks:
        print(toks[0].strip())
```

with the csv module, map the opened file on a csv reader, iterate on the rows, print first (stripped) row.

```
import csv
with open ('n-emails.txt') as f:
    cr = csv.reader(delimiter=",")
    for row in cr:
        print(row[0].strip())
```

the second method has the advantage of being robust to commas contained in cells, quotes, ... that's why I recommend it.

Comment: thanks so much can I please ask one more think.. the first cara is ">" how can I remove that too so I only have the eamail address